# Error while pushing django app to heroku master

Tags: python, heroku

When I push my django app to heroku master, I get an error about the version of python

I already added a file runtime.txt with python-3.7.2 and added python-3.7.2 to the requirements file.

Collecting python-3.7.0 (from -r /tmp/build_56ed5608dd6394891e58f29a1dd224c2/requirements.txt (line 5))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-3.7.0 (from -r /tmp/build_56ed5608dd6394891e58f29a1dd224c2/requirements.txt (line 5)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for python-3.7.0 (from -r /tmp/build_56ed5608dd6394891e58f29a1dd224c2/requirements.txt (line 5))

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're supposed to have any "python" version in the `requirements.txt.` My `requirements.txt` is for a extremely basic application, but it only has this:

```
gunicorn 
django-heroku
django
```

Requirements are for the "extra" things. If you have the [buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python) set up for python, I don't think you'll need it in `requirements.txt` at all.

I actually don't have a `runtime.txt` because heroku can configure that automatically, but I don't think that's the issue you're running into.

Comment: I edited my requirements file to contain the following:
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.7
gunicorn==19.9.0
psycopg2-binary==2.7.7
whitenoise==4.1.3

I still receive the same error message

Comment: Not too sure than to be honest. I'm pretty new to Heroku, and I would think you need to change python versions to the supported ones (3.7.1, 3.6.7, etc) on the buildpacks page

Comment: Turns out I needed to push to my repo first after removing the python version from requirements.txt before pushing to heroku master.